# How to load partial view with parameters in angular

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

How do I load a partial view with passing a parameter using ng-repeat in angular?

Something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in collection track by $index">
    @Html.Partial("_PartialView", {{item.id}});
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Repeaters don't work in Angular the way they do in ASP.  The element (and its children) that ng-repeat is attached to will be repeated.  So for your 'partial view', you would do:

```
<div id="repeatContainer">
    <div id="repeatedContent" ng-repeat="item in collection track by $index">
        <ul>
          <li>{{item.id}}</li>
          <li>{{item.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

If collection is `[{id: 1, name:'something'}, {id:2, name:'other thing'}]`, this will result in:

- 1
- something

- 2
- other thing

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand. Where is the partial view loaded?

Comment: I've updated my example.  There is no 'partial view' here, but you are using the repeater wrong regardless.  If you really need to separate the content into its own file, you should use a directive.